# Problema para instalar o nodemon

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Estou aprendendo Node.JS e tem uma parte que preciso instalar o nodemon.

Uso o comando:

```
npm install nodemon@1.19.4 -g
```

E ao verificar a versão do nodemon usando:

```
nodemon -v
```

Me aparece este erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui, fazendo da forma de acessar o Visual Studio Code como administrador, entrar na pasta que está meu projeto, no terminal digitar:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

E quando rodo

```
nodemon-v
```

Aparece a versão.